# Killing functions by successive differentiation.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials

It is clear that a polynomial function $f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \dots + a_n x^n$ has the property that some derivative of $f$ vanishes. (Of course, it's the $(n+1)$-th derivative.) One can also check that the reverse implication is true: if $f^{(n+1)}(x) = 0$ (identically), then $f$ has to be a polynomial of degree at most $n$. (There is even a stronger fact, namely if for any $x$ there is $n$ with $f^{(n)}=0$, then $f$ is a polynomial, but that's beside the point here.) If one takes a polynomial-logarithmic function $f$ made up of terms like $x^a \log^b x$, where $a,b$ may be taken rational, then the similar thing remains true: there is $n$ such that $f^{(n+1)}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Such functions have polynomial growth: they are bounded by $x^N$ for some $N$ (and for sufficiently large $N$).

I would like to know to what extent the reverse is true: Suppose that $f$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}_+$ and smooth, and that for some $n$, $f^{(n+1)}(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$. Is it true that $f(x)$ is bounded by $C x^N$ for some $N$, $C$? Can one take $N=n$?

Comment: Your "stronger fact" is not true if you talk about smooth functions $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. $f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac1{x^2}}&\text{if }x\ne0,\\0&\text{if }x= 0\end{cases}$ has $f^{(n)}(0)=$ for all $n$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: I think the condition to his stronger fact is supposed to be read as $\forall x\colon\exists n\colon f^{(n)}(x)=0$, which is not true for your $f$. It might be refuted by something like piecewise polynomial functions though.

Comment: @Abel Ah, the ambiguity of "any" strikes again. And right, your interpretation *would be* refuted by piecewise polynomials if they were smooth (which I guess is also supposed to be a condition)

Comment: Well, sufficiently differentiable would suffice. I'm thinking of something like $f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \leq 0 \\ x^2 & x>0\end{cases}$. For $x\leq 0$, $f^{(0)}(x) = 0$ and for $x>0$ $f^{(3)}(x)=0$. I don't need $f^{(3)}$ to exist everywhere.

Comment: Concerning the extra fact: apologies for the imprecise formulation. What is true is the following: Suppose $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is infinitely many times differentiable, and for each $x$ there exists $n$ (dependent on $x$) such that $f^{(n)}(x) = 0$. Then, $f$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that the mean value theorem implies fairly easily that, if the derivative of a function is bounded by a polynomial of degree $d$ (for large values of the argument), then the function itself is bounded by a polynomial of degree $d+1$.  So in your situation, if $f^{(n+1)}$ tends to $0$ and therefore is bounded by a constant, then $f^{(n)}$ is bounded by a linear function, $f^{(n-1)}$ by a quadratic one, etc., until $f$ is bounded by a polynomial of degree $n+1$.

It's not clear to me whether the additional information, that $f^{(n+1)}$ tends to $0$ as opposed to merely being bounded, will significantly improve the bound on $f$.  The problem is that $f^{(n+1)}$ could tend to $0$ extremely slowly.

Comment: $f^{(n+1)}\to 0$ gives us additionally that the leading coefficient of our polynomial can be chosen arbitrarily small. However, this does not allow to decrease the degree ...

Comment: Thank you! This is just what I needed; somehow I got struck thinking on the problem from just the wrong perspective.